# I wish to have my figures and tables in place and remove relevant code from endfloat

Tags: endfloat

I have a document using floats and endfloat and causing a headache – I wish to have my figures and tables in place and remove relevant code from endfloat.

Which lines of code shall I remove from the following MWE?

```
documentclass[3p,authoryear,preprint,12pt,onecolumn]{elsarticle}
\long\def\twocolumn[#1]{#1}
\makeatletter\@twocolumnfalse \makeatother
\usepackage[nomarkers, nolists,tablesonly]{endfloat}



%\usepackage{tabulary,graphicx}

\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{} 
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{tabulary,xcolor}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\let\save@ps@pprintTitle\ps@pprintTitle
\def\ps@pprintTitle{\save@ps@pprintTitle\gdef\@oddfoot{\footnotesize\itshape \null\hfill\today}}
\def\hlinewd#1{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height #1
  \futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline}
\def\tbltoprule{\hlinewd{.8pt}\\[-12pt]}
\def\tblbottomrule{\hlinewd{.8pt}}
\def\tblmidrule{\noalign{\vspace*{6pt}}\hline\noalign{\vspace*{2pt}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\ifNAT@numbers \biboptions{sort&compress}\fi}
\makeatother

  

  


\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage[]{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=TeX}
\else 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi 
\ifluatex\else\usepackage{stmaryrd}\fi

  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Following additional macros are required to function some 
% functions which are not available in the class used.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{url,multirow,morefloats,floatflt,cancel,tfrupee}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{textcomp}{}{\usepackage{textcomp}}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}
\urlstyle{rm}
\makeatletter

%%%For Table column width calculation.
\def\mcWidth#1{\csname TY@F#1\endcsname+\tabcolsep}

%%Hacking center and right align for table
\def\cAlignHack{\rightskip\@flushglue\leftskip\@flushglue\parindent\z@\parfillskip\z@skip}
\def\rAlignHack{\rightskip\z@skip\leftskip\@flushglue \parindent\z@\parfillskip\z@skip}


\if@twocolumn\usepackage{dblfloatfix}\fi 
\AtBeginDocument{
\expandafter\ifx\csname eqalign\endcsname\relax
\def\eqalign#1{\null\vcenter{\def\\{\cr}\openup\jot\m@th
  \ialign{\strut$\displaystyle{##}$\hfil&$\displaystyle{{}##}$\hfil
      \crcr#1\crcr}}\,}
\fi
}

\let\lt=<
\let\gt=>
\def\processVert{\ifmmode|\else\textbar\fi}
\let\processvert\processVert

\@ifundefined{subparagraph}{
\def\subparagraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{2\parindent}{0ex plus 0.1ex minus 0.1ex}%
{0ex}{\normalfont\small\itshape}}%
}{}

% These are now gobbled, so won't appear in the PDF.
\newcommand\role[1]{\unskip}
\newcommand\aucollab[1]{\unskip}
  
\@ifundefined{tsGraphicsScaleX}{\gdef\tsGraphicsScaleX{1}}{}
\@ifundefined{tsGraphicsScaleY}{\gdef\tsGraphicsScaleY{.9}}{}
% To automatically resize figures to fit inside the text area
\def\checkGraphicsWidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \tsGraphicsScaleX\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}

\def\checkGraphicsHeight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>.9\textheight
    \tsGraphicsScaleY\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}

\def\fixFloatSize#1{}%\@ifundefined{processdelayedfloats}{\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics{#1}}\ifnum\wd0<\columnwidth\relax\renewenvironment{figure*}{\begin{figure}}{\end{figure}}\fi}{}}
\let\ts@includegraphics\includegraphics

\def\inlinegraphic[#1]#2{{\edef\@tempa{#1}\edef\baseline@shift{\ifx\@tempa\@empty0\else#1\fi}\edef\tempZ{\the\numexpr(\numexpr(\baseline@shift*\f@size/100))}\protect\raisebox{\tempZ pt}{\ts@includegraphics{#2}}}}

%\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\ts@includegraphics[width=\checkGraphicsWidth]{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\includegraphics{\@ifnextchar[{\ts@includegraphics}{\ts@includegraphics[width=\checkGraphicsWidth,height=\checkGraphicsHeight,keepaspectratio]}}}

\def\URL#1#2{\@ifundefined{href}{#2}{\href{#1}{#2}}}

%%For url break
\def\UrlOrds{\do\*\do\-\do\~\do\'\do\"\do\-}%
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\makeatother
\def\floatpagefraction{0.8} 
\def\dblfloatpagefraction{0.8}
\def\style#1#2{#2}
\def\xxxguillemotleft{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\guillemotleft}
\def\xxxguillemotright{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\guillemotright}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\emergencystretch 15pt \def\floatpagefraction{0.8}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Well, simply remove (or comment) loading of `endfloat` on line 4.

Answer (score 0):

Use these two packages

1. `\usepackage{float}`;
2. `\usepackage{flafter}`.

and also use `[H]` option with the figures and the tables.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/Figure1.jpg}
  \caption{No-way}
  \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: if you use `[H]` then the `figure` is not a float so  the `flafter` package does nothing.

Comment: Did you try @Bernard 's suggestion?